# How to create a object of the server in the client?

Tags: python, game-engine, network

I have a server and a client.

The general idea is that the client just gets input from the user and sends it to the server, which updates the scene. Every frame the server updates the common scene according to the clients input and sends each client the current scene.

My current progress is that each client that connects has its own avatar, he can move and see the others.

1. I want to allow the server to send every type of object, a table for example. I think that the best way to do this is if the server will send each client a bpy script of every new object. The client will run it in a way that it will be the same as in the server.
2. I want the server to send for every old object everything about it relates to the world- position, rotation, scale etc.

Again, my main goal is to have clients that get input and send it to the server and a server that receives inputs from the clients, updates the common scene and send it for each client.

Any simple and deep suggestion will be great ! thanks.

Comment: Is this question for usage in Blender Game Engine?

Comment: Yes, it's not the right place to post it?

Comment: Yes, it just wasn't clear how you were intending to use Blender in the solution. Also, I think you should narrow down the question to something more specific, otherwise your post will likely be closed for being too broad. Perhaps something related to a specific script to handle client/server communication.

Comment: The answer to this question relates only to blender. the server and the client are blender game engine files, using sockets. I really tried to be specific: 1. i need a way to send an object of the server to the client and suggested bge to do it, but I don't no how to apply it. 2. I need a way to apply all the object changes- such as rotating or scaling (I'm currently sending only the world position of every object and it works). If you think that I have to be more specific than that, could you please tell me what is too general?

Comment: This is too broad because it deals with several topics each with a lot of possible solutions. It is ... networking. 1. Establish a connection. 2. extract status data from scene 3. send data. 4. apply received status data to scene.  Btw. bpy is the Blender API. You can't use it with the BGE. You need the BGE API.